# Looking for a better way to write 'Credential verifier'

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, tuples, user-input

I just started learning python (using Python 3.12.1)
And I wanted to write a code for verifing the user's input of username&password with a bunch of credentials store in tuples.

I use each tuple for each username&pass.
I also have each condition for them.
It works, but the conditions will only keeping growing everytime i add more tuples

I'd like to be able to write fewer conditions that will verify all user's input with the tuples.

```
class credential():
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.user = (username, password)

serah = credential('serah','0168')
bob = credential('bob','0110')
kevin = credential('kevin','0440')

def log_in():
    name_input = input('Username: ')
    password_input = input('Password: ')
    verify = (name_input, password_input)
    if verify == serah.user:
        print('hello ',name_input)
    elif verify == bob.user:
        print('hello ',name_input)
    elif verify == kevin.user:
        print('hello ',name_input)
    else:
        print(False)
        
user_input = log_in()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "database".  It can be a text file, a CSV file, a JSON file, or a real database like SQLite.  Use a loop -- you don't want all the user name objects in your program.  It should be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's comment is spot on, but to address the problem you specifically mention, you have a few options:

**Iteration.** Keep all of the users in a single [iterator](https://realpython.com/python-iterators-iterables/). Iterate throw them and find an exact match. This is not a time-efficient solution, and will not scale.

**Hash table.** Create a hash table (that's called Dictionary in Python), keep usernames as keys and passwords. If the input username exists in the "database", get its value (i.e. password) and compare with the input password. If they match, log in is successful, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

The `log_in` function already prints the result, so you don’t need to assign its result to `user_input`. Instead, you can directly call the function:

```
log_in()
```

Also, the message “hello” is printed for all valid logins. If you want to print a specific message for each user, you might consider storing additional information in the credential class and adjusting your `log_in` function accordingly.